# WCF RESTFul Service - 404 error while passing "+" in parameter

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting an error `404 - File or directory not found` while accessing the w c f URL in as below

```
http://testService.com/Test/service.svc/GetLocalProducts/VITAMINS+
```

however if I am removing the "+" from the end I am getting the proper result.

Note: the type is `POST`.

Please let me know any other configuration I am missing for the same.

Comment: I noticed you call it RESTfull.. But REST should never contain any actions. You used `GetLocalProducts`, which then should be `LocalProducts`.

What the actual problem is with the + ? I don;t know, maybe provide some controller code?

Comment: Have you tried this work around? http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/60/404-Error-in-IIS-7-when-using-a-Url-with-a-plus-sign-in-the-path